# How to remove certain rows from a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may seem like its been asked before, but before calling it a duplicate please fully read ;)

I have a table

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-master-row k-state-selected"></tr>
    <tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
    <tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Each row that has a class of 'k-master-row' can have a row of class 'k-detail-row'. If the k-master-row has a related k-detail-row then its directly below it like this

```
<tr class="k-master-row"></tr>
<tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
```

Now the issue I am running into is that I need to remove all the k-detail-rows, EXCEPT the detail row that is this

```
<tr class="k-master-row k-state-selected"></tr>
<tr class="k-detail-row"></tr>
```

So if the k-master-row has a class of k-state-selected, I need to keep its k-detail-row and remove the other k-detail-rows.

I know I can remove the k-detail-rows by using

```
$('#MyTable .k-detail-row').remove()
```

but that removes all the k-detail-rows, which is not what I want..

So, in short, using either jquery or javascript, how do I remove all the detail rows that is not related to the master-row that has class of k-state-selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic appears to be that you wish to delete all `.k-detail-row` elements that do not *immediately* follow an element with `k-state-selected`.

In which case:

```
$('#MyTable :not(.k-state-selected) + .k-detail-row').remove();
```

In other words, delete all `.k-detail-row` elements whose immediately-preceding sibling is not an element with `.k-state-selected`.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I am going to have to look more into this :not that you used. I'll mark as answer once I am able to. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Edited to provide some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i appreciate that. so that + signs means immediately preceding?

Comment: Immediately *pro*ceeding. So `foo + bar` matches all `bar`s that immediately follow (i.e. are immediately *pre*ceded by) a `foo`. This is standard CSS, too, not jQuery.